Prove $B:=\left\{\frac{y}{y-1}:y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}\right\}$ is not bounded below nor above.
Given $$B =\left\{\frac{y}{y-1}:y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}\right\}$$
prove that $B$ is not bounded below nor above.
I was thinking of using contradiction of the lemma below. Is that correct, or can I just prove it with limits? Is there any other way to prove this question?
Lemma:
An upper bound $u$ of a nonempty set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the supremum of $S$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $s_\varepsilon \in S$ such that $u - \varepsilon < s_\varepsilon$.
My attempt:
Suppose $B$ bounded above so there exist $\sup B$.
Let $u = \sup B$

$1 + \frac{1}{y-1} \leq u$, for all $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$
For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $1 + \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1} \in B$ such that

$u - \varepsilon < 1 + \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1} \leq u$
Choose $\varepsilon = 1$, there exist $1 + \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1} \in B$ such that
$u - 1 < 1 + \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1} \leq u$
$u - 1 < 1 + \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1}$
$u - 1 - 1 < \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1}$
$u - 2 < \frac{1}{y_{\varepsilon}-1}.$
I got stuck in here.
Could you please help me? How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

For more info as in Anne Bauval's answer, see this.

Proof:
Not bounded above: Suppose that the set $B$ is bounded, then $1+\frac{1}{y-1}\leq u$ for some $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{1\}$. By choosing $y=3$, we have $u\geq \frac{3}{2}$. Thus, $\frac{1}{u}$ exists and $\frac{1}{u}+1\neq 1$. Let $y=\frac{1}{u}+1$, we have $1+\frac{1}{y-1}=1+u\leq u$, a contradiction here. Thus, $B$ is not bounded above.
The other part is similar to the above argument, I'll leave it to the reader.
One can also use the definition of limits to do it:
For the upper bound, we need to show that $$\lim_{y\to 1^+}1+\frac{1}{y-1}=+\infty.$$
$$\forall M>0,\exists \delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{1}{M-1}\right\}, s.t.\ \text{whenever}\ 0<y-1<\delta,\ \text{we have}\ \left\vert 1+\frac{1}{y-1}\right\vert>M.$$
Edit: Suppose that $1+\frac{1}{y-1}\geq u, \forall y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{1\}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}$, then by choosing $y=\frac{2}{3}$, we have $u\leq -2.$  Then by choosing $y=1+\frac{1}{u-2}$, we have $u-1\geq u$, which is a contradiction.

Sorry, I would like to ask how you got $u \geq \frac{3}{2}$? Also, why does $\frac{1}{u}$ exist, and why is $1 + \frac{1}{u} \neq 1$? Thank you.

@mathstudent $u\geq 1+\frac{1}{y-1}, \forall y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash{1}$, so  $u\geq 1+\frac{1}{\color{red}{3}-1}$. Since $u\neq 0$, $\frac{1}{u}$ exists and $1+\frac{1}{u}>1+0>1$

Alright, thank you.  I also have a question about how to prove that $B$ is not bounded below using the same method. So, suppose $1 + \frac{1}{y - 1} \geq v$
for $v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus {1}$. Then I chose $y = 0$, so that $v \leq 0$. However, I am stuck. How should I proceed from here? Thank you.

Why the downvote?

@mathstudent Please see my edit.

Okay, thank you

@mathstudent Could you tell me why you removed the acceptance of my answer? Is there something wrong?

Ohh, sorry, I might have clicked it accidentally on another tab.

As commented before you however included the details of your attempt, for your problem (about bounds), your lemma (about the supremum) is off topic, and looking at limits would have been a better idea. (Comment now self-deleted.)
A more expeditious method is the following. The map $$y\mapsto\frac y{y-1}$$ is surjection from $X:=\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$ onto itself (it is even an involution of $X$, i.e. a self-inverse bijection). Therefore, its image (your $B$) is $X$, which is neither bounded below nor above.
